Prioritize routes in NetworkManager when using custom IP with DHCP fallback
I'm using network manager to set a custom IP address, but also keeping DHCP activated in case I connect my headless device to another network, I automatically sets the default gateway and everything. However, I want to prioritize my custom IP over the DHCP-generated one.
This is my config:
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.33/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --

Which creates the following routing table:
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.107 metric 100

But I want the src 192.168.1.33 route to have a lower metric, and the other one to be used as a fallback. Is this possible using nmcli (NetworkManager)?

Maybe not the answer you are looking for but it is recommended the other way around, check this answer out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269830/how-to-set-static-ip-with-fallback-to-dhcp

Well, I set both dhcp and static addresses. In this post, he want to set one, and if that fails, then the other. My case is like having two NICs connected on the same network, and assigning a different priority to each.

There's no need to delete the other route. Just add the new route with the ipv4.routes config option, like this: set ipv4.routes 192.168.1.0/24 50 src=192.168.1.33.
This will generate the following config:
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               192.168.1.11,192.168.1.12
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.33/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            { ip = 192.168.1.0/24, mt = 50 src=192.168.1.33 }
ipv4.route-metric:                      99
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.link-local:                        0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv4.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)

Which creates the following routing table:
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.107 metric 99
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto static scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 50
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 99
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.107 metric 99


Note: The 99 metric was used to check what that config changes and what doesn't change

